# Add bootstrap 5 to angular 12

Tags: bootstrap-5, angular12

This is crazy and maybe stupid but this is what is happening

I created a new clean Angular12 project `ng new proj --strict` (I selected scss).
I added bootstrap 5 `npm install bootstrap` 
I added the following line to `styles` sections

```
"styles": [
   "src/styles.scss",
   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
]
```

That is it, neither `bootstrap.css` nor the `bootstrap.js` is loading in the page

[image]

1. I did `ng serve` a thousand times and it did not work
2. I tried `"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` did not work
3. I tried `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"` did not work
4. I tried to import bootstrap from the style.scss like this 
   `@import url("../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css");` 
   still does not work
5. bootstrap does exist in the `node_modules` folder, no problem.
6. I was trying with this from yesterday, It must NOT be that hard, I am adding bootstrap 5 to angular 12 !!!!!!, I am frustrated.

Comment: Hey Hakan, did you by any chance figure this out? Having the exact problem, never before has this occurred.

Comment: @MartinCodes yes I found a dirty solution that I did not like at all but it was the only thing that worked, I added bootstrap as a link element to the `index.html` page and it worked

Comment: `<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">` adding this to the `index.html` was the dirty solution